# Moment.js formatting incorrect

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I'm using `moment.js` for my react-native project datetime formater. I want to remove the timezone from utc date. For my timezone is GMT+8000, so for utc offset is correct, when when I add `format('YYYY/MM/DD 00:00')`, result subtract one day.

`console.log(moment.utc());`
 **->** `Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: Wed Jul 11 2018 11:08:57 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time), …}`

`console.log(moment.utc().utcOffset(new Date().getTimezoneOffset()));`
 **->**`Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: Wed Jul 11 2018 03:08:57 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time), …}`

`console.log(moment.utc().utcOffset(new Date().getTimezoneOffset()).format('YYYY/MM/DD 00:00'));`
 **->**`"2018/07/10 00:00"`

Any idea how ? Or maybe I doing it wrong ?

Comment: @Li357 I not need to offset the timezone myself to get the utc without timezone ?

Comment: @Li357 yes, but as I `console.log(moment.utc())` the result is added `GMT+8000` and time is `Wed Jul 11 2018 11:08:57` , when i offset `Wed Jul 11 2018 03:08:57`, it subtract 8 hour, it this should be correct ?

Comment: "*I want to remove the timezone from utc date*", but UTC dates don't have a timezone. Are you just trying to remove the Z? If your timezone is +0800, then until 8 am local time it is the previous date UTC (e.g. 11 July 7:59 am local is 10 July 11:59 pm UTC).